# How to count the number of row keys for a particular column_family in Cassandra (read details)

Tags: python, database, count, cassandra, pycassa

I am trying to load data from SQL to No-SQL i.e Cassandra. but somehow few rows are not matching. Can somebody tell me how to count the number of row keys for a particular column_family in Cassandra.

I tried get_count and get_multicount, but these methods require keys to passed, In my case i do not know the keys, Instead I need the row count of the row_keys. 
list column_family_name gives me the list but limited to only 100 rows. is there any way,
I can override the 100 limit.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get a row count for a column family. You have to perform a range query over the whole column family instead.

Comment: @jterrace Thanks, can you please elaborate about performing the range query? (with a example preferably)

Comment: All i want is, how can I use the corresponding SQL query in cassandra. "select count(row_key) from table_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get a row count for a column family. You have to perform a range query over the whole column family instead.

If `cf` is your column family, something like this should work:

`num_rows = len(list(cf.get_range()))`

However, the [documentation for get_range](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/columnfamily.html#pycassa.columnfamily.ColumnFamily.get_range) indicates that this might cause issues if you have too many rows. You might have to do it in chunks, using `start` and `row_count`.

Comment: Thanks, but it takes a very long time to execute. Still figuring out how cassandra(NOSQL) is efficient to retrieve data. I do agree its faster to insert millions of records at once, but not retrieval! :(

Comment: are you using randompartitioner?

Comment: you have to use a partitioner, even with one node

Comment: If you set column_count=0 and filter_empty=False in get_range(), this will give you just the keys back.  Additionally, get_range returns a generator, so you can do something like "for key, _ in get_range(): count += 1" so that you're not pulling the entire result into a list at once.  There's no need to use 'start' and 'row_count' if you do this; pycassa will chunk the requests automatically.

Comment: @TylerHobbs. Thanks. Count was helpful, But i found few keys missing. To get the keys back, i set column_count=0 but could not find filter_empty to set it False.  I get this `TypeError: get_range() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filter_empty'`  Any clues..?

Comment: @Nish filter_empty was only added in pycassa 1.3. You might have an older version?

Comment: In that case you should either upgrade to 1.3 as jterrace suggests, or set column_count to 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can count Cassandra rows without reading all rows.

See the [implementation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#counting-rows) in Spark for `cassandraCount()` which does this quite efficiently.